# Dotnetbrowser JSValue

Tags: vb.net, dotnetbrowser, jsvalue

I installed dotnetbrowser and my Visual Studio 2015 with netframework 4.6.1 not working the Javascript:
My header:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports DotNetBrowser.Browser
Imports DotNetBrowser.Engine
Imports DotNetBrowser.WinForms
```

Thanks before!
[Error code here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1a1OK.png)

Comment: Please paste the code in the question so that other users can replicate it and offer an answer

Comment: Here is my code: https://pastebin.pl/view/a16824b9

Comment: check this: https://dotnetbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000109870-working-with-jsobject

Comment: its not helped me , because my problem not this.